# Calling UI button externally with 4.3 [repeat Q - version change]

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

With 4.0, this was possible through pretty hacky interfaces, but possible: [Calling UI button externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236559/calling-ui-button-externally)

Now, I've switched all over to 4.3, and, I cannot seem to get the "old" functionality working.

[Exception with toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTg75.png).
[Exception without toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mChBF.png).

What has changed? Or, what is the 4.3 way of doing so?

Comment: Why not `editor.execCommmand( name )`?

Comment: Yeah I get the feeling of an XY problem from both this and the original question. If not, don't worry - Reinmar will think of something :D